# Why my image source is not working for my current local machine but it's working for the web sources?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

I have a div and I want to show images as `innerhtml` using the back end C# code. So that I can generate them as I want them to. In here for `innerhtml` everything is running fine but the images. While I am giving it a path from my current localhost the images are not showing but while I am putting an web url its working why?

Even if I tested taking the suggestion from the visualstudio like I put a static image in front end and took its path but its still not working. I user the `server.mappath(test)` this function too.

```
test = "App_Data/images/37id4.jpg";
divfifth.InnerHtml ="<img src='"+test+"' />";
```

This says the path is not found here is my code given.
if anyone can suggest me to generate these in better way please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Borshon Aeolus Saydur , Its a nice question. Try to give add path like "~/images/.." format. instead of "Images/..".

Comment: yes i tried that too but its not working i guess its something wrong with my local server .can u help me on that what are the typical problems regarding this?

Comment: can i now the path showing in the html is right. check once with inspect element. if it is wrong adjust from there. after adjusting, if the image came check the url. and also one thing is your folder have permission to access that file?(means IIS_User has assess )

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it by moving my image folder one layer up.although i dont know what was the wrong in previous layer.but its now working after moving it to its upper layer..